# Sufficiency and completeness of truncated distribution

Tags: self-study, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics, truncated-distributions

*[From [Theory of Point Estimation](https://amzn.to/3iBEYJY) (Lehmann and Casella, 1999, Exercise 6.37)]*

> Let $P=\{P_\theta:\theta \in \Theta\}$ be a family of probability
> distributions and assume that $P_\theta$ has pdf $p_\theta$. Let $A$
> be a fixed Borel subset of the sample space. For each distribution
> $P_\theta$, we consider the truncated distribution $P_\theta^\star$ on
> $A$, i.e., $$ P_\theta^\star (B) = \frac{P_\theta(A\cap
>   B)}{P_\theta(A)} $$ or  $$
>   p^\star_\theta(x)=\frac{p_\theta(x)}{\int_Ap_\theta(y)dy}, x\in A $$
> and $0$ otherwise.
>
> Denote $P^\star=\{P^\star_\theta:\theta \in
>   \Theta\}$. Show that
>
> (a) If $T$ is sufficient for $P$, then it is sufficient for $P^\star$
>
> (b) if, in addition, $T$ is complete for $P$
> it is also complete for $P^\star$.

I know the same question was asked and given a hint [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496061/completeness-of-a-statistic-in-a-truncated-distribution), but I can't really understand it. Here's how I do (a):
$T$ is sufficient for $P$ iff it is sufficient for $\theta$. Then we have
$$
p(x|\theta) = g(T(x)|\theta)h(x)$$
Let $l(x)=h(x)$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise, then
$$p^\star(x|\theta) = g(T(x)|\theta) l(x)/c$$ for some constant c, so $p^\star$ is sufficient for $\theta$ and thus for $P$.
Is this proof valid?
Also, it would be really nice if someone could show me how to prove part (b). I am thinking about extending the nonzero $g$ if $T$ is not complete for $P^\star$, but I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Hint: I would not validate this answer because $c$ is not a constant.

Comment: Hint (b): start from the definition of completeness applied to $P^*$, by assuming $g\circ T$ having zero expectation under $P^*$ and deduce what happens to $(g\circ T)\mathbb I_A$ under $P$.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right general idea, but your "constant" is not actually constant, so you need to be more careful.  Since $T$ is sufficient in the initial problem, let $p_\theta(x) = g_\theta(T(x)) h(x)$ be the Fisher-Neyman decomposition for that density.  Since $B$ is assumed to be known$^\dagger$ you have:

$$\begin{align}
p_\theta^\star(x)
&= \frac{p_\theta(x)}{\int_B p_\theta(x) \ dx} \cdot \mathbb{I}(x \in B) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{g_\theta(T(x)) h(x)}{\int_B g_\theta(T(x)) h(x) \ dx} \cdot \mathbb{I}(x \in B) \\[12pt]
&= g_\theta^\star(T(x)) h^\star(x), \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

where the functions in the new decomposition are:

$$g_\theta^\star(x) \equiv \frac{g_\theta(T(x))}{\int_B g_\theta(T(x)) h(x) \ dx} 
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
h^\star(x) \equiv h(x) \cdot \mathbb{I}(x \in B).$$

---

$^\dagger$ Note that if $B$ is an unknown parameter then $T$ is not sufficient.